# Converting from natbib to biblatex

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I want to use chicago manual style, which does not seem to be available for natbib, so I want to use biblatex instead.

Since I have in-text citations, I followed the previous answers and tried this:

```
\usepackage[natbib=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{dotbibfile}

\printbibliography
```

But my in-text citations won't show up, they show up as keys, like `lupu2017legacy`

What should I fix to make in-cite citations show up?

Comment: Biblatex shows the citation keys when the corresponding entry was not found. You either don't have that entry in your bib file or you didn't run `biber` to produce the `.bbl` file.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Ok, I misunderstood biblatex...thank you.

Comment: The title of your query, "Converting from natbib to biblatex", verges on being misleading. For sure, it betrays a good dose of confusion. Had you written "Converting from natbib/bibtex to biblatex/biber", the title itself would have told you right away what was missing: a `biber` run. `bibtex` and `biber` are both standalone, external programs. `biber`, being much newer, is also far more powerful and versatile than `bibtex`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains brilliantly why you need to run Biber (or BibTeX). If you have worked with `natbib` before, you quite probably know that you have to run BibTeX and with `biblatex` you just run Biber instead. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 explains how you can get your editor to help.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I produced the .bbl file, but when I try compiling, the the in-text citations are still off...

Comment: @user2298759 If you ran `biber` and got the `.bbl` file, another run of LaTeX should put the citations in the right place. If not, something's wrong. Take a look at the `.blg` file (or better, upload it and show us) and see if you find any error message.

Comment: Any news here? At the moment all we can say is that the symptoms in the question suggest you failed to run Biber. As such your question is a duplicate of the classic https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. If there is more to your issue, then we need to see more information: What exactly are you doing? What output do you expect? What output do you get instead? What does the `.blg` file say? Are the any errors or warnings in the `.log`? ...

Comment: Any news here? As mentioned above the question is a bit low on the details and so in its current state the question appears to be a duplicate of the standard "run Biber" questions. If there is no new development here in due time I will vote as such.

Comment: I voted to close the question as duplicate of our classic 'run Biber' question. If running Biber is not enough, please edit your question with more information and ping me. I will happily vote to reopen if more details are added.